# Problema com password_verify() no PHP

Tags: php, php-7

Minha intenção é chamar um redirecionamento de página caso a senha não esteja correta usando header(), porém, percebi que não estava funcionando. Fui reduzindo os testes e cheguei até aqui:

```
// Senha Certa
$senha = 'Teste123';
// Senha Errada
$senha = 'Teste1234';

// hash que combina com a senha 'Teste123'
$hash = '$2y$10$QW0qR0mI1oOB733baaleSe.aXwwAhJlpV6G5vOprKqP14HdcbECO.';

// Verificação da senha
if(!password_verify($senha, $hash)){
    header("Location: acesso-negado.php");
    //die("Usuário ou Senha Invádios");
}

header("Location: index.php");
```

Colocando a senha errada, percebi que ele ignora o header("Location: acesso-negado.php") e continua normalmente até chegar no header("Location: index.php") e finalmente ser redirecionado.

Percebi também que se colocar um die() embaixo do header("Location: acesso-negado.php") ele começa a funcionar corretamente.

Alguém sabe o porque do redirecionamento só ocorrer com o uso do die() abaixo dele? Estou usando o php 7.2.7

Comment: Deve haver alguma confusão, ou a variável retorna true e executa a condição ou não .

Comment: Exatamente, estou achando tudo muito estranho. Vamos ver se alguém faz o teste e conta se também esta tendo o mesmo problema.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Talvez não esteja muito claro pra você, mas a função `header` não faz nada além de cuspir uma string na saída, antes do corpo da requisição HTTP. Quem trata o header Location e deve fazer o redirecionamento é o cliente.

Por isso, se quer que a totalidade da sua resposta seja o header Location, você precisa encerrá-la por conta própria após emitir esse header, usando [`exit`](https://php.net/exit), ou o `die` como sugerido na outra resposta. Caso contrário, seu código segue executando normalmente, e acaba emitindo um segundo cabeçalho.

Comment: Meu Deus, em alguma parte obscura da minha aprendizagem em php comecei a usar o header() imaginando que ele fazia um "redirecionamento obrigatório" da página. Isso a muito, muito tempo atrás e agora vejo que está tudo errado, header() nada mais é do que manipulação do cabeçalho da requisição HTTP. Que viagem absurda... Obrigado!

Comment: Na verdade é uma confusão bem comum :) E, pra ser completo, não é 100% verdade que a função só emite o cabeçalho, como eu disse acima; no caso do header Location, ela também causa a definição do status code retornado como 302.

Comment: Estava dando uma olhada aqui na documentação e me assustei com quanta coisa da pra fazer com o header(). Atribuir dados de cookies, especificar tipos de cache, passar dados de documentos, download e etc. E eu aqui usando para redirecionar páginas de forma errada rsrsrs :O

Answer (score 2):

Seu código está correto. A única coisa é que para dar certo, precisa terminá-lo após o `header("Location: acesso-negado.php");`, caso contrário, ele irá continuar até o próximo `header` normalmente e o outro "Location":

```
// Senha Certa
$senha = 'Teste123';
// Senha Errada
$senha = 'Teste1234';

// hash que combina com a senha 'Teste123'
$hash = '$2y$10$QW0qR0mI1oOB733baaleSe.aXwwAhJlpV6G5vOprKqP14HdcbECO.';

// Verificação da senha
if(!password_verify($senha, $hash)){
    header("Location: acesso-negado.php");
    die; // <-- Finalizando aqui
}

header("Location: index.php");
```

Comment: Eu tinha percebido que precisava do die(); mas não entendia o porque. Agora entendi que o header() é apenas uma manipulação de cabeçalho e não um redirecionamento imediato. De qualque forma obrigado amigo.

Comment: Isso aí, é bem comum se confundir com isso ^^